# Turn MATLAB code into Python

Tags: python, matlab, sorting, indexing

I am a newbie in Python so I am in trouble with vectorized operations and indexing in Python. I completely understand how to rewrite it in C - style with element-by-element computation, but it wouldn't be "pythonic" and laconic as MATLAB code. I want it be short and laconic. I need to translate the next code from MATLAB into Python:

```
for t=2:size(cl, 1)
    hasData=find(isfinite(retGap(t, :)) & op(t, :) < buyPrice(t, :) & op(t, :) > ma(t, :));
    [foo idxSort]=sort(retGap(t, hasData), 'ascend');
    positionTable(t, hasData(idxSort(1:min(topN, length(idxSort)))))=1;
end
```

All of the arrays are 1500x497 floats. I can translate the first line like this:

```
posCl = cl.iloc[t]
posOp = op.iloc[t]
posBp = buyPrice.iloc[t]
posMa = ma.iloc[t]
posRg = retGap.iloc[t]
posRg[pd.notnull(posRg) & (posOp < posBp) & (posOp > posMa)]
```

But I have no idea how to translate the lines with sorting in a laconic way.

Comment: Step 1: learn Python. Step 2: code Python. Alternatively, hire a programmer, this is not a code conversion service.

Answer (score 4):

- Python is zero-indexed
- MATLAB is 1-indexed
- MATLAB slice notation includes the endpoint
- Python slice notation excludes the endpoint
- MATLAB start:step:stop
- Python start:stop:step

useful links : 
- http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html
- http://www.matlabtricks.com/post-23/tutorial-on-matrix-indexing-in-matlab

Comment: Thank you, but what you wrote is obvious for me. I am in trouble with the exactly that code. I completely understand how to rewrite it in C - style with element-by-element computation, but it wouldn't be "pythonic" and laconic as MATLAB code. I want it be short and laconic.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem!

```
for t in range(len(cl)):
idx = retGap.iloc[t][pd.notnull(retGap.iloc[t]) & \
                 (op.iloc[t] < buyPrice.iloc[t]) & \
                 (op.iloc[t] > ma.iloc[t])].sort_values()[:10].index
positionsTable.iloc[t][idx] = 1
```